# How to get dropdown ID from sumo select dropdown?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I cannot get the dropdown ID from sumo Select dropdown.The dropdown id was changing dynamically. More than one dropdown available on a page.Below the sample code.

```
 <div id="shareOnFriendsList" > 
        <select id="friendsList_<?php echo $postID;?>" class="testSelAll" multiple="multiple" placeholder="Share On Your Friends" title="Select & Share Your Friends" >
            <?php 
            $sql_getFriends = "SELECT id, CONCAT(firstname,' ',lastname) AS username FROM register WHERE id IN($friend_id[0])";
            $getFriends_row = mysqli_query($con, $sql_getFriends);
            while($row =  mysqli_fetch_assoc($getFriends_row))
            {
            ?><option value="<?php echo $row['id'];?>" > <?php echo $row['username'];?> </option><?php
            }?>                   
       </select>       
    </div>
```

In my javascript, I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {         
    window.testSelAll = $('.testSelAll').SumoSelect({okCancelInMulti:true, selectAll:true });               
        $('.btnOk').on('click', function() {                                
            var obj = [],
            selectedFriendsList = '';
            $('.testSelAll option:selected').each(function(i) {
                obj.push($(this).val());
                $('.testSelAll')[0].sumo.unSelectItem(i);
            });
            for(var i=0;i<obj.length;i++) 
            {selectedFriendsList += ',' + obj[i]};              
            alert('.testSelAll select').attr('id'); //get select id..       
        });
    }); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have wrong selector to target select element. it should be:

```
$('select.testSelAll').attr('id')
```

Comment: It's getting only first dropdown id. Here more than one dropdown is available. I want to get current clicked dropdown id.

Comment: share html that has btnOk in it